# Can the GUE be thought of as a uniform point in a high-dimensional polytope

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, random-matrices

I have thought about this question for a long time and could only find partial answers.

The Gaussian Unitary Ensemble (or [GUE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_matrix#Gaussian_ensembles)) is the eigenvalues of a random Hermitian matrix with complex Gaussian entries.  For example, the eigenvalues are known to follow the Wigner semicircle distribution

$$ \mu_{N \times N} = \tfrac{1}{N}\sum \delta_{\lambda_i} \to \frac{2}{\pi}\sqrt{1 - x^2 }\, dx$$

In [Queues and GUEs](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.42.4911), Baryshnikov shows the eigenvalues of the minors the minors don't just interlace, if we condition on the spectrum of $H$ the eigenvalues are uniform in the Gelfand-Tsetlin polytope.

- Let $H$ be the random GUE matrix
- Let $H_k$ be the $k \times k$ upper left corner.
- The eigenvalues of $H_k$ and $H_{k+1}$ interlace.
- The eigenvalues of $H_1, \dots, H_N$ form a Gelfand-Tsetlin triangle
- Conditioning on the eigenvalues of $H$ the eigenvalues of the minors are uniform in the Gelfand-Tsetlin polytope.

Cedric Boutillier's discussion of says his [bead model](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0607162) is a bi-infinite analogue of this uniform interlacing picture for GUE.

---

I am no longer sure it's possible to sample the eigenvalues of the GUE matrix as a uniform element of a polytope since the last row, the eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $H$ are distributed in a highly non-uniform way.

Is it possible to prove the Wigner semicircle law this way.  Boaz Klartag writes a [central limit theorem](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605014) for high-dimensional convex sets.

> Let $X$ be a random vector uniformly distributed in a convex polytope $K$ then
>   $$ \left| \mathbb{P}[\langle X, \theta \rangle \in A] - \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_A e^{-t^2/2} dt\right| < \epsilon$$
>   where $X$ is centered $\mathbb{E}[X] = 0$ and isotropic $\mathrm{Cov}[X_i X_j] = \delta_{ij}$.

This point of view on large deviations could make sense since all the "stuff" for a high-dimensional polytopic is concentrated near the center.  Is it possible to prove the Wigner semicircle formula along these lines?

Comment: Interesting question.  I used Boutillier's bead model with an MCMC sampler to (hopefully) approximately sample GUE eigenvalues as an undergrad.  IIRC the statistics looked pretty good.  I think I sampled $2N+1$ strings of beads and then looked at the beads on string $N$, i.e. NOT at the edge of the bead pattern.